# Issue with adding a responsive carousel

Tags: javascript, css, html, carousel

I am trying to implement a carousel slideshow on my test website but when copying the existing HTML, CSS and JS code it does not appear in the way it is supposed to. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Please follow this guide to provide all details in your questions, so community can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Very minimum - is to include your code in question.

Comment: What did you try so far?